# Split numbers from text

Tags: python, string, split, ironpython

I want to split a string that contains numbers and a metric unit. I tried this:

```
foo = "10mm"
match = re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)", foo, re.I)

num = match.group(1)
unit = match.group(2)
```

Which works with integers but not if the number contains a comma. What do I have to change for that?

Comment: Do you mean a thousands separator comma, or a decimal comma?

Comment: decimal comma like 10.12

Comment: That's a period, not a comma. The difference is crucial because the dot is a regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow `10` or `10,0` but not `,,,`, `,123` or `123,`, then you can use

```
match = re.match(r"([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?)([a-z]+)", foo, re.I)
```

If you actually meant a dot/period (`10.0`), then you need to remember to escape it:

```
match = re.match(r"([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)([a-z]+)", foo, re.I)
```

Comment: @Yui: Define "works". Would you say that matching `10&0mm` is correct? The dot matches *any* character unless escaped.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.split('[a-z]+', foo, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['10', '']

>>> re.split('[0-9]+', foo, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['', 'mm']
```